# Extracting Observed Object into subview behaves differently than just one view struct. Why?

Tags: class, swiftui, instance

This doesn't work the way I intended it…

When an error occurs in `MyClass` instance the user is advised to check the settings app and then come back to my app. The next time my app is opened it should just retry by initializing `MyClass` all over again. If the error persists it will just again display above everything else. (Actually I would like to just `fatalError()` my app but that isn't best practice, is it?) So I thought I just initialize a new instance of `MyClass`…

```
class MyClass: ObservableObject {
    static var shared = MyClass()
    @Published var errorMsg: String? = nil
    func handleError() -> Void {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.errorMsg = "Sample Error Message"
        }
    }
    init() {
        self.errorMsg = nil
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var theObj = MyClass.shared
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Text("App when everything is fine")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        MyClass.shared.handleError()
                    }
            }
            VStack {
                if theObj.errorMsg != nil {
                    VStack {
                        Spacer()
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Text(theObj.errorMsg!)
                                .font(.footnote)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    print("theObj.errorMsg! = \(theObj.errorMsg!)")
                                }
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .background(Color.red)
                }
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { phase in
            switch phase {
            case .active, .inactive:
                if (MyClass.shared.errorMsg != nil) {
                    MyClass.shared = MyClass()
                    print("Error cancelled. Retry at next launch...")
                }
            default:
                ()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As I said: this doesn't work.

Very surprisingly the following variation works… I thought it couldn't work like this but it does. My big question is: WHY does it work like this? Shouldn't this be the same thing? What's the difference that I don't see?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Text("App when everything is fine")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        MyClass.shared.handleError()
                    }
            }
            ErrorMsgView()
        }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { phase in
            switch phase {
            case .active, .inactive:
                if (MyClass.shared.errorMsg != nil) {
                    MyClass.shared = MyClass()
                    print("Error cancelled. Retry at next launch...")
                }
            default:
                ()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ErrorMsgView: View {
    @ObservedObject var theObj = MyClass.shared
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if theObj.errorMsg != nil {
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Text(theObj.errorMsg!)
                            .font(.footnote)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                print("theObj.errorMsg! = \(theObj.errorMsg!)")
                            }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                .background(Color.red)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also I honestly don't understand how do I conclusively kill the MyClass instance I don't need anymore? I do know how to terminate the background tasks that MyClass is running, but is it sufficient to just assign a new instance to the `static var shared` and the old one is purged?

Comment: Why do you need to "conclusively kill the MyClass instance"? You have set it up essentially as a Singleton when you use `MyClass.shared`. That means that you are using one instance and sharing it with anything else that needs to use it. If you are only using it in one place, and don't need it again when that is done, then insatiate it by calling MyClass(). That gives you a new instance that will be discarded with the view. This still may not solve your problem in that unless that app is killed, then you will still have this instantiation. The value needs to be changed at some point.

Comment: I just want to make sure that everywhere I am accessing the .shared instance it will be the new instance and not the old one... plus I'd like it to free up the memory.

Comment: Except where you are accessing the shared instance it is ALWAYS the old instance because you are only making 1 instance and sharing that 1 instance. It will not be deleted so long as somewhere something is using it, and you will have references all over the place. The issue isn't the `MyClass` object, it is that you are not resetting it's value when you tell the user to go out of the app. So, when the user comes back, the app is still in the state of "there is an error, go out of the app" when it needs to be in a state of "test to see if there is an error".

Comment: Thx. Now I know for sure I need another way to retry. I still don't know how I'll be doing it, only not this way.

Comment: I have a hunch why there is a difference between two versions: unlike stucts, objects are passed by reference rather than by value. When you first do @ ObservedObject var theObj = MyClass.shared, theObj contains a reference to the initial shared object and, when you do MyClass.shared = MyClass(), you change the static MyClass.shared, but theObj remains the same. In other words, using @ ObservedObject and MyClass.shared = MyClass() does not work as you would expect. The easiest way around it would be to add a "reset" function to MyClass and call it instead.